# Model parallel for arch that doesn't fit in 1 GPU

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow, distributed

I have a tensorflow model that is too big to fit into a single TITAN X GPU. I do however have access to 4 such GPUs. Does tensorflow support a model parallel training paradigm where different GPUs are training different layers of the same net?

If so, where can I find resources that help me do do this?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn#training_a_model_using_multiple_gpu_cards

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov This is data parallelism! A copy of the entire model is being placed on each GPU. I want to have different parts of the model on different GPUs since all of it doesn't fit on one GPU!

Comment: You can just assign your different variables/ops to different devices.

Comment: @Fake Doing that still doesn't let me fit the models. I'm still seeing GPU memory allocation corresponding to the full model on of the GPUs.

Comment: @AbhijatBiswas Have you been able to resolve this? I am stuck with a similar issue as well

Comment: @Reuben_v1 Yes, I moved to pytorch which let me do this easily.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks. I guess I'll have to look towards pytorch as well. Tensorflow is just way too demanding